# Simulating input in Labview

Tags: serial-port, simulation, labview

I am trying to write a Labview program that takes input from a thermal sensor on serial port RS - 232, applies some basic transformation to it, and displays it on a screen.

I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow simulate the sensor in labview, or by using some external simulator application so I can test my program before I'm given access to the actual hardware.

Is this possible?

I have Labview 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to test your VI's logic would be to make a CSV file of example data, and temporarily replace the section that reads from the sensor with a section that reads data values from the CSV file at the same rate.

It's probably not worth trying to emulate the serial port input at a lower level as Labview is generally very reliable at getting data from hardware into your VI - it's up to you then what you do with it!

Answer (score 1):

You could have another program simulate the sensor and write to a different COM port. Then you could connect these COM ports with a null modem cable.

In order to do so, you'll have to work out how your sensor works and feed data in na appropriate format into that 2nd COM port. These data will end up being received by the 1st COM port and eventually by your application-to-be-developed.

Comment: having another program simulate the sensor is good idea. What I was looking for were details on how to do it.

Comment: I don't know your sensor - that's what you'll have to find out. But I added a basical idea how to go with this approach.

Comment: I've often also used com0com to simulate a null modem cable (handy when you haven't got any or enough ports) for testing RS-232 applications : http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you encapsulate all of your communications code in a subVI or set of subVI's, separate from the code that does the transformation and display part, you can easily substitute test code and test data for the real sensor data. You could write a subVI that generates the test data and replace it with the real sensor comms subVI later, or you could use a case structure in the subVI to choose between communicating with the real sensor and just outputting test data (which, as Moray suggests, you could read in from a file so that you can easily change it).

I would suggest that you write separate subVIs for opening communications to the sensor, getting a data point from it, and closing the comms port when you are finished (though you can probably just use the serial or VISA close function for that). Chain these VIs together using the comms port (aka VISA session) and error wires. The 'open' VI could take an input that specifies whether real/simulated data is to be used and store that choice in a global variable (or a functional global VI) which the 'get data' VI checks each time it is called.

glglgl's suggestion of sending the simulated data from another serial port is also good; all you need to do here is use the serial send and receive functions in some sort of loop to do the same thing as the real sensor would, in terms of receiving commands and sending an output back. This has the advantage that you don't need to make any changes to your main program which should work exactly the same whether it's connected to the real sensor or the simulation program. However, problems with serial comms in the real world often result from instruments or devices that don't do exactly what their specifications claim they do, so just because your program works perfectly with your simulation doesn't guarantee it'll work perfectly with the real sensor if the real sensor does something you didn't expect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though the other answers offered some really great ideas, I've found an easier way to simulate sensor input that would be convenient for beginners.

1. Create virtual serial ports on your computer by using a Virtual port simulator. http://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp/
2. Get a Modbus simulator. http://www.plcsimulator.org/
3. Download Labview Modbus Library. http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/epd/p/id/4756

Open the Labview Modbus library and run 'MB Serial Master Example.vi'

Now it should be possible to read/write values into the simulator using the example program.

The Block Diagram of example program can be analyzed to find out how data is being transferred behind the scenes on Modbus protocol.